# Regex for characters appearing in order

Tags: javascript, regex

Still relatively new to regex, I'm trying to find the expression for finding characters by order:

For example:
Given the string abc I want to make an expression which will match the first a, the first b after that a, the first c after the b, etc.

i.e. given "**abc**"

The big c**a**t **b**uys bananas, **c**arrots and chicken.

Comment: You can probably do it without regex, can you post your code so far?

Comment: The reason I'm trying to achieve this in regex is to use it in the context of this highlighting plugin: http://beatgates.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/extend-jqueryhighlight-to-highlight.html Which accepts a regular expression to determine which characters should be highlighted.

Comment: `.*` means “match any number of any character”. Take it from there!

Comment: @ioseph are you trying to highlight the individual letters only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `a.*?b.*?c` could do the job.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it put me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise regex can only match on a continuous block of chars. In the end I wrote my own highlighting function below:

```
function r(str, search) {
            // assumes search.length > 0
            var searchChars = search.split('');
            var search = '';
            var replacement = '';
            for(var i=0, cnt=searchChars.length; i<cnt; i++) {
                            var c = searchChars[i];
                            search += c.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/, "\\$1") + '(.*?)';
                            replacement += '<span class="highlight">' + c + '</span>$' + (1+i);
            }
            return str.replace(new RegExp(search, 'i'), replacement);
}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that regex is not well suited for this task.